# csom javascript get Document Libraries with particular Content Type

Tags: content-type

I need to filter result to particular content types fo document library. I cannot seem to retrieve the content type of library. How is this possible. When I try with 
`oList.get_contentTypes()` object object is being returned.

```
function retrieveAllListProperties() {


    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
    clientContext.load(collList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var listInfo = '';
    var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title()  + oList.get_contentTypes() + '\n';
    }
    alert(listInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oList.get_contentTypes()` returns a collection and hence it needs to be iterated to get information about each content type.

**UPDATE**

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
var collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
clientContext.load(collList, 'Include(ContentTypes, Title)');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var listInfo = '';
    var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title()  + '\n';
        var ct_enumerator = oList.get_contentTypes().getEnumerator();
        while (ct_enumerator.moveNext()) {
        var ct = ct_enumerator.get_current();
        var contentTypeName = ct.get_name();
        alert(contentTypeName);
    }
    }
    alert(listInfo);
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args)
{     alert('error'); }
```

Comment: Hi doesnt output anything, seems to hang on var ct_enumerator = line.
Would it fail if array null ? Does CT need to be expicit Load?

Comment: Try the updated code.

Comment: Thats worked! it shows all the CT's associated with the Library including hierarchy. Not to go on a tangent but is it also possible to exclude empty document libraries?

Comment: Perhaps open a different question for that.